# Rspec for mailers with I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, internationalization, actionmailer

I don't understand how to test with rspec and internationalization.
For example, in requests tests I do

```
I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
  visit users_path(locale: locale)
  #...
end
```

and it works just fine: every locale tests correct.

But in mailers this trick doesn't work.

**user_mailer_spec.rb**

```
require "spec_helper"

describe UserMailer do
  I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user, locale: locale.to_s) }
    let(:mail_registration) { UserMailer.registration_confirmation(user) }

    it "should send registration confirmation" do
      puts locale.to_yaml
      mail_registration.body.encoded.should include("test") # it will return error with text which allow me to ensure that for each locale the test call only :en locale email template
    end
  end
end
```

It runs few times (as many as many locales I have), but every time it generate html for the default locale only.

When I call `UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver` from controller, it works fine.

**user_mailer.rb**

```
...
def registration_confirmation(user)
  @user = user
  mail(to: user.email, subject: t('user_mailer.registration_confirmation.subject')) do |format|
      format.html { render :layout => 'mailer'}
      format.text
  end
end
...
```

**views/user_mailer/registration_confirmation.text.erb**

```
<%=t '.thx' %>, <%= @user.name %>.
<%=t '.site_description' %>
<%=t '.credentials' %>:
<%=t '.email' %>: <%= @user.email %>
<%=t '.password' %>: <%= @user.password %>
<%=t '.sign_in_text' %>: <%= signin_url %>
---
<%=t 'unsubscribe' %>
```

I repeat - it works fine for all locales.
I have the question only about rspec tests for it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have to wrap your test in a `describe/context` block to allow the `it` block to see your `let` variables:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe UserMailer do
  I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
    describe "registration" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user, locale: locale.to_s) }
      let(:mail_registration) { UserMailer.registration_confirmation(user) }

      it "should send registration confirmation" do
        puts locale.to_yaml
        mail_registration.body.encoded.should include("test")
      end
    end
    # ...
  end
  # ...
end
```

As for why, perhaps [this StackOverflow answer on `let` variable scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5554123/567863) may help.

#### Edit

Is the issue that you've assigned a locale to your user, but you don't pass it into the `mail` method anywhere?  Perhaps [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11097855/567863) would be of reference.  Hopefully one of the two answers there would be relevant in your situation.  Here's my simple attempt at adapting the first answer there to your situation (untested obviously):

**user_mailer.rb**

```
...
def registration_confirmation(user)
  @user = user
  I18n.with_locale(user.locale) do
    mail(to: user.email, 
             subject: t('user_mailer.registration_confirmation.subject')) do |format|
      format.html { render :layout => 'mailer' }
      format.text
    end
  end
end
...
```

Comment: Thx, Paul, but it doesn't work.
The variables works fine. And as you can see it's already included in `describe UserMailer` block. It's the way to define variables for the whole bunch of tests.

Comment: Okay, my second thought is that perhaps the `mail` method needs the locale passed into it.  See my edit and the StackOverflow link mentioned in it.  Hopefully that isn't too similar to @eugen's answer.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. My user_mailer.rb actually didn't have any locale's mentions. But..it works correct. I tested it and it sends different emails according to the locale. That's why I said I don't understand how it works:)
Nevertheless I tried your suggestion. After implementation rspec expected default locale and got non-default locale every time, for all locales. It's weird. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Yeah, that is weird... If you do end up getting a solution, please share it!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to specify the locale, as in:

`mail_subscribe.body.encoded.should include(t('user_mailer.subscribe_confirmation.stay', locale: locale))`

You can also try adding `I18n.locale = user.locale` right before the `mail` call in the `registration_confirmation` method.

Comment: Then without seeing the entire code for UserMailer and the test there's not much else to suggest. The other thing is that in the `let` block you define `mail_registration`, but in the actual test you're using `mail_subscribe` - it seems an inconsistency, but again, without seeing the entire code I can't say.